# Backbone - Geolocation

Tags: backbone.js, geolocation, maps

I'am a new Backbone user and started to implement Google Maps in it. I set this up in de View object. I works all fine, but when i go to another page (template with the navigator object) and go back to the page with Google Maps, the current position dont market on the Google Map.

Below my code from my View

```
DFM.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: $("#content"),

template: $("#rankings_template").html(),

// Initialiseren
initialize: function(){

    self = this;
    this.render();

    var location_destiny = new google.maps.LatLng(52.476716,4.799623);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_maps'), {
        center: location_destiny,
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false

    });

    if(navigator.geolocation){

        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(update_user_location, error_handler, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            frequency: 3000
        });

    } else {
        console.error('Geolocation: 0 - Geotracking not available'); 
    }

    // Update user location
    function update_user_location(position){
        location_user = new google.maps.LatLng(52.474716,4.798623);

        var marker_user = new google.maps.Marker({
             title: 'Gebruiker',
             position: location_user,
             map: map,
             draggable: true,
        });
    }

    // Error handler
    function error_handler(error){
        console.error('Geolocation: ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
    }

    var marker_destiny = new google.maps.Marker({
         title: 'Bestemming',
         position: location_destiny,
         map: map,
         draggable: true,
    });
},

render: function(){

    this.$el.html(_.template(this.template));

    return this;
}
```

});

Comment: Is the initialize function get called firsttime you visit the page and second time you visit the page? this.render() needs to be bind with your model like this this.model.bind('reset', this.render);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question right but for me it helped calling `google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');` every time after triggering the map route.

PS: a bit late, but maybe it helps someone in the future